# how to install pg_dump and pg_restore to the heroku

Tags: heroku

I have to load pg_dump and the pg_restore to Heroku so that I can load a local database to Heroku. How can I install pg_dump and pg_restore on Heroku? What are their addresses?

Comment: This works different on Heroku. Read this article: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-postgres-import-export

Comment: @MerynStol but heroku says I could not found pg_dump file

Answer (score 2):

So they way Heroku works is you install an addon to your Heroku app called Heroku Postgres.  Then you add another app called PGBackups.  These apps expose commands to your command line.  They are like subcommands to the heroku command.  So you'd do heroku pgbackups:restore to restore (or really, load initially) a database to your Heroku instance.  See this link:

https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-postgres-import-export